# Static cell contact picker

Tags: uitableview, swift, contacts, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to accomplish the following: 
1. my tableview consists of two static cells
2. the cells have an initial text of "select contact"
3. a modal should pop-up with a contact picker
4. the user should pick a contact
5. the static cell's text should be updated to match the contact's name

I'm having the following problems. If I assign the delegate to my tableviewcontroller, I can't seem to get it to work with two contacts (without having to write separate functions for each).
I would very much like a single function which returns a contact.

I have been experimenting, and this is the best I can come up with (its a partial implementation of didSelectRowAtIndexPath which should open a contact-modal. However, it does not appear to follow the delegate's functions.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    class PeoplePickerDelegate:NSObject, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate {

        func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!) {

            let firstName: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue()
            let lastName: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty).takeRetainedValue()

            println("name is \(firstName) \(lastName)")
        }

        func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson person: ABRecordRef!) -> Bool {

            peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker, didSelectPerson: person)

            peoplePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

            return false;
        }

        func peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!) {
            peoplePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    var peoplePickerDelegate:PeoplePickerDelegate?

    let picker = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = peoplePickerDelegate
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm a novice and trying really hard to grasp this.